# Тире или запятая в конце?

Tags: пунктуация

Многие девушки задаются вопросом, можно ли обойтись без визажиста. Если будущая невеста является профессионалом в области макияжа – то да.

Answer (score 2):

И то и другое будет верно. Тире ставят при интонационном подчёркивании придаточных предложений, стоящих впереди. У Вас как раз такой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

**Интонационное тире** перед второй частью союза в СПП с разной структурой предложений ставится **при желании выделить условную часть предложения**, например:

(1)   Если гель ― **то да, с водой**. Молочком просто так протирают, а гель надо на мокрое лицо наносить. И ее ― забыли? Если судить по прессе ― **то да**.

(2) Достаточно часто  встречается **другой вариант постановки тире** (в этом случае после "да" обычно следует **распространенное утвердительное предложение**):

Что касается тактики достижения этой стратегической цели, **то ― да, здесь им выбраны иные приоритеты.** Если вспомнить российскую Конституцию, **то ― да, имеет право знать**. А если так, **то ― да, лучше, если бы она состоялась.**
Если под «продукцией более полусотни российских издательств» можно понимать беспорядочно сваленные книги молодых русских авторов, **то ― да, издательства были весьма широко представлены.**

Я ответила, что если вещество не токсично, **то ― да**.

Answer (score 0):

«Если, то...» Эта схема второй фразы, где ДА равно утверждению МОЖНО, а тире подразумевает ОБОЙТИСЬ: то обойтись можно. Первой же фразе не помешает отчётливый вопрос. В результате будет так.

Многие девушки задаются вопросом: можно ли обойтись без визажиста? Если будущая невеста является профессионалом в области макияжа, — то да.